# C-mount lens filter and focal length

Tags: optics, lenses, camera

I'm building an eye-tracking system for mice.
For that, I am using a monochrome camera that would capture Infrared Light out of an 850nm LED, and a zoom lens to refocus the image when needed.
I also purchased a c-mount lens filter to restrict the incoming light to the above-mentioned wavelength. However, after mounting the filter, I am unable to achieve focus no matter how much I adjust the focal length of the lens.
I came across a suggestion that an extension ring of 1mm might help resolve this issue, but I have been unable to find any credible sources to back this claim. I would like to know if this is a viable option or if there are other alternatives to refocus the image (other than purchasing a filter that mounts in front of the lens).

FL range of the camera: 8.50 - 90mm

Working distance: 150mm-∞.

Filter length: 20.3mm

I would appreciate your help and if you need further info, I'd be happy to answer!

Comment: Is the filter between the lens and focal plane or between the lens and the mouse?

Comment: Depending on what response(s) you get here, you might consider moving your question to the Photography stack exchange.